# MySQL UPDATE, IF, INSERT INTO statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to follow the following [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert/)  and use an UPDATE, IF, INSERT INTO statement seeing that it will no go over my data twice.

Please note it is for php.

The statement that I have is as follows

```
$query = "UPDATE 
            " . $this->table_name2 . "
        SET  
            batch = :batch, 
            created = :created
        WHERE 
            id = :id
        IF row_count() = 0 
        INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name2 . "
        SET 
            id=:id, 
            batch=:batch, 
            created=:created";
```

But my return value always comes back as false, and I do not know where the problem is.

If I try the first half of the statement it updates the information:

```
$query = "UPDATE 
            " . $this->table_name2 . "
        SET  
            batch = :batch, 
            created = :created
        WHERE 
            id = :id
```

And if I try the second half of the statement it INSERTS the information:

```
        INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name2 . "
        SET 
            id=:id, 
            batch=:batch, 
            created=:created";
```

I do not find any help after allot of searching so far, and I feel that somehow my IF statement may not be correct, but I do not even get info on the `IF row_count() = 0` in the docs.

Comment: If can only be used in stored procedures, not as part of SQL statements

Comment: @ JochenJung O ok, there is something else that I have to learn then. What alternative statement would you suggest I use that will be the quickest if you don't mind?

Comment: You are maybe looking for the on duplicate key update version of the insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF statement is available in stored procedures only.

If `id` is the primary key (or unique) this should work for you:

```
INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name2 . "
       SET
            id = :id, 
            batch = :batch, 
            created = :created
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            batch = :batch, 
            created = :created
```

This will execute the INSERT statement only, of the ID does not exits yet. If it already exists, it will execute the UPDATE part.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!!

Comment: Hi JochenJung, I just changed the quotes after the first `created = :created` to after the second `created = :created` to make it work. Regards

Comment: You are right, they do not belong there. Just fixed it in my answer